# Concatenating lines from a textfile into a paragraph and output it to another file

Tags: c++, string

```
// Assignment7.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream infile;
int index = 0;
string singleWord;

infile.open("text.txt");


while (!infile.eof()) //to figure out size of array
{
    infile >> singleWord;
    index++;
}

string* strings = new string[index];

infile.close(); //to restart the file at the first word
infile.open("text.txt");
int count = 0;

while (!infile.eof())      //if not at end of file, continue reading numbers
{
    infile >> strings[count];
    cout << strings[count] << " ";
    count++;
}
infile.close();       //close file

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("textfixed.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    outfile << strings[i] << " ";

}
outfile.close();
delete[] strings;
strings = NULL;

return 0;
}
```

My program reads a textfile that has 6 sentences setup as such:

Sentence 1

Sentence 2

Sentence 3

Sentence 4

Sentence 5

Sentence 6

I'm learning how to play with strings, and I want to concatenate the 6 sentences so that in a new file(that my program would write to, called newtext.txt) would have it setup like: Sentence 1. Sentence 2. Sentence 3. Sentence 4. Sentence 5. Sentence 6. So for example, if the textfile contained something like:

I like to play soccer.

I enjoy eating apples.

I am 18 years old.

I watch baseball sometimes.

Cooking is a hobby of mine.

My birthday is in July.

My program would take the above^ and in a new file write it out as:

I like to play soccer. I enjoy eating apples. I am 18 years old. I watch baseball sometimes. Cooking is a hobby of mine. My birthday is in July.

I'm just not quite sure how I go about concatenating each word in order to setup as such. If anyone could point me into the right direction, that'd be appreciated. Thanks.

## UPDATED OP WITH NEW CODE

I don't get any output from the newly updated code, it's supposed to cout() the new paragraph to console but when I run it the CMD is just black

Comment: Your first step is to figure out the `while (!infile.eof())` [is always a bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). You can start by fixing your code so it reads the file properly.

Comment: If you are using string, you can use '+' for concatenation.

Comment: @WasiAhmad I'm trying to figure out how though using the words taken into the array, would it be each index that i'd have to concatenate?

Comment: @Xor i would suggest you to read files line by line and then do concatenation. You can do the concatenation character by character as well, either way it should work!

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you're making it too complicated.  As you read each line in, write it out to the out file, just don't add a new line until it's done:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile( "Text1.txt" );
    ofstream outFile( "Text2.txt" );
    string sentence = "";
    while ( getline( inFile , sentence ) )
    {
            outFile << " " << sentence;
            cout << " " << sentence;
    }
    outfile << '\n';
    cout << "\nPress enter to continue";
    while ( cin.get() != 10 )
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```